# use camera as subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i'm using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera in my app, but a want to add the camera view a subview. not as modal view.

now i'm using

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

i want to use it like this, but doesn't seem to work ..

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.delegate = self;
[picker.view setFrame:CGRectMake(300, 40, 300, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

i know that the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera only can be used as modal view.
How is for example Hipstamatic using this for example?

Comment: I assume Hipstamatic is using modal UIImagePickerController (without controls), but overlay it with own custom views.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible in iOS 4+ using the [AVCaptureSession framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  It's much more complicated than using UIImagePickerController, but you have complete control over input and output. The key to having the camera view as a subview is the following code.  Assume you have a subview called previewView that you want to show the camera view:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
previewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds; 
[self.previewView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

There is more setup work to do to give your AVCaptureSession object the correct input and output devices and to actually capture the photos.  That can be found in the documentation and examples on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the only supported methods for displaying a UIImagePickerController seem to be `presentModalViewController:animated:` or UIPopoverController.

I'm not familiar with Hipstamatic, but chances are it is using [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008072), in particular [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).

Comment: "Available in iOS 4.0 and later." I've never used Hipstamatic, but I think it's older than iOS 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) to get idea how things can be accomplished. Look out for AVCam Demo in developer.apple.com resources for IOS programme. You will definitely get idea how it works. You should be registered developer with APPLE, and thats very easy.

Hope it helps.